# Get value from string if finded match regex

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

Imagine i have a list of string´s like this:

> **Hello Word 132 132 132 GoodBye!!**  Should return 132132132
>
> **Hello Word 132 132 GoodBye!!** Should return nil
>
> **132 132 132 GoodBye!** Should return 132132132
>
> **132132132 GoodBye!** Should return 132132132
>
> **1321321321GoodBye!** Should return nil
>
> **132 132 1321** Should return nil

How can i check whether the phrase has 9 followed algorithms, or separated by space, and get that same number?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
(\d{3})(\s?\1){2}
```

and remove any whitespace in the match.

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/fX9cN0/1) BTW, if you don't want to match in

> Some123 123 123Thing

you can use word boundaries `\b(\d{3})(\s?\1){2}\b`

Comment: @DaSilva glad to have helped :)

Comment: i founded a problem in my application, so i need a extra validation. i edit my question, if you know how to help me i appreciate. Anyway, thanks again for your help